# Is there any problem with my sql statement about 'union all'?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to find the number of results (# of rows) of the following sql statement.

```
    select distinct table1.column1, 
                    table2.column2
      from table1, 
           table2

 union all

    select table1.column1, 
           table2.column2
      from table1, 
           table2;
```

The numbers of results of the first and second queries are **30** and **100**, resp.
I *expected* that the result is **130**, but the *actual* result is **60** (=double of the first results?).

Also, the result of the following statement is **200**;

```
    select table1.column1, 
           table1.column2
      from table1, 
           table2

 union all

    select distinct table1.column1, 
                    table1.column2
      from table1, 
           table2;
```

I dont know why it is. Thank you.

Comment: No JOIN conditions needed?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? Which version?

Comment: Any explain/execution plan?

Comment: I use Oracle 11g. Each query just gives cross join results.

Comment: Looks like an optimizer issue.

Comment: Your expectation is correct. If one query returns 30 rows and the other 100, then the two union all queries should return 130 rows each. So this must either be an error in the DBMS or in the tool or app you are using to display the data. Knowing Oracle, it is very unlikely the error is in the DBMS.

Comment: Are table1 and table2 base tables or views?

Comment: Oh thank you. I will try again with another version.

Answer (score 0):

You are joining the same result distinct and not distinct  ..  this should return only the not distinct (second result)  (

if the columns are the same you don't need  a union all

but just

```
 select distinct table1.column1, 
                table1.column2
  from table1, table2
```

or 
     select table1.column1, 
                    table1.column2
      from table1,  table2

depending of the fact you need  distinct result or all result

anyway  you should not obatin  nor  130  or 200  but only 100 result